Are you allowed to make videos about games and upload them to YouTube?
Assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuhu! PLEASE READ TO THE END. Recently I have read that if you depict a statue or drawing of living beings it is a likening of the power of Allah. and I want to make a video on YouTube about video games where there are models of people but they are virtually assembled as a sculpture is it allowed for me to make a video on YouTube about these games. Naturally about shirk games and speech can not be, but here are games where there are no gods and nothing sinful, but there are images in the video game characters can I shoot these games on video or stream? (Streaming is to play games live and comment) answer please as reliable and understandable I am just very afraid to accumulate sins.
